# HTML divs not properly displaying as a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need to put these divs into a grid so that they display on the screen in a grid as opposed to a block. I have them displayed in a block and centered on the screen for smaller screen widths and after a certain screen width I would like them to display as a grid, but I keep getting the buttons and text displaying to the right of the images as opposed to displaying under the images. Here is my HTML and CSS code...

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="wrapper-2">
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/shirt-men-181dmv4-600.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim fit blue plaid shirt</h2>
        <p>$50.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://watchdreamer.com/sites/default/files/styles/soldat_md/public/2021-05/WBP201A.BA0632_.png?h=7afb1587&itok=EH_sMV2B" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's silver and black time piece</h2>
        <p>$499.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>  
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Brown-Men-Shoes-PNG-Image.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's Uncle Tom dress shoes</h2>
        <p>$44.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b19cdda5-932f-4862-a7b3-b7440bfb759e_1.87f4ae5495ec75a86d5f6e4572e807d3.jpeg?odnHeight=612&odnWidth=612&odnBg=FFFFFF" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's slim black slim fit dress pants</h2>
        <p>$70.00</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
      <p class="border-bottom" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="800"></p>
      <div class="boxes" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800">
        <img src="https://www.suitsexpert.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/silk-tie.png" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
        <h2>Men's formal red tie</h2>
        <p>$19.99</p>
        <button class="arrivals-buttons">Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<style>
.container-2 {
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.boxes {
display: grid;
justify-content: space-evenly;
grid-template-columns: 220px 220px 220px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: There is nowhere in your CSS `display: grid`. Probably you should use media queries.

Comment: As @Zakk said, you don't use `grid` anywhere, and when you do your p-elements would take up place in your grid I think?

Comment: I purposely did not add the "grid method" I used to the CSS my apologies. I have updated the code to show you what I have used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change .boxes class. When grid-template-columns property is used, it will create columns that put your text and button to the side of your image.

```
.boxes {
        display: grid;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Also, you can add width and height to your image so that it does not go out of the grid width.

Comment: This is the issue that I was having... it would display the text and button to the right of the image. Is there any way to have these elements displayed under the image when I am using the grid method?

Comment: Try this solution and try to change .boxes class in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `display:grid;` at the boxes you want to be a part of the grid. But you put it in the container. This would be an example

```
.container-2 {
  display:grid;
  gap:1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
}
```

then you can remove the `.wrapper-2` element

Comment: I am not able to submit a screenshot so I would not be able to show you exactly whats happening, however, overall your method worked, but for select photos, they are being displayed unusually. For example my 3rd div with the image of the shoes is being displayed after my 1st div and the image width is also cut off. It is also not in a straight row with the others. It is below the other divs in the same row.

Comment: Try
`object-fit: cover` in the image. Also remove `grid-template-rows` if you dont want rows